# jsdoc: multiline description @property

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I am documenting my code using jsdoc, so far so good, I have a comment like below

```
...
* @property {string}  mode -  mode of display 'video' - display video or 'audio' - play only the audio.
* @property...
```

and it comes in html document like

```
| ...   |         |                                 
| mode  | string  | mode of display 'video' - display video or 'audio' - play only the audio.|
| ...   |         |
```

I want it to appear something like

```
| ...   |         |                                 |
| mode  | string  | mode of display                 |
|       |         |   'video' - display video       |
|       |         |   'audio' - play only the audio.|
| ...   |         |                                 |
```

hope I am making myself clear...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post some examples of what got you to this point so that others have a jumping-off point and can better guide you.

Comment: try to insert <br>-tags, this could work if they would not be escaped...

Comment: @Stonz2, this is more configuration related, searched the net without much luck, also I am quite new to jsdoc, not even sure what to try, and the source http://usejsdoc.org is not of much help

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach thx, ```mode of display <br>&nbsp&nbsp 'video' - display video <br>&nbsp&nbsp 'audio' - play only the audio.``` did the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `br`-Tags to resolve new new lines:

```
mode of display <br>&nbsp;&nbsp; 'video' - display video <br>&nbsp;&nbsp; 'audio' - play only the audio.
```

Comment: This does not help avoid very long lines **in the source file**.

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski: that was not the question... Feel free to add a answer which solves that problem as well or start a new question for it ;)

Answer (score 24):

By using a `minus` sign you can avoid `<br>` (moreover not working in vscode)

```
  /**
   * @property {String} editMode editing mode
   * - A: description for A
   * - B: description for B
   * - C: description for C
   */
```

getting a bullet list:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

for this you can simply add two line spaces
instead of one
for example:

this

```
/**
 * decription
 * modes:
 * I am foo
 * I am bar
 */
```

results to :

> decription modes: I am foo I am bar

**But**

this

```
 /**
 * decription
 * 
 * modes:
 * 
 * I am foo
 * 
 * I am bar
 * 
 */
```

results to :

> decription
>
> modes:
>
> I am foo
>
> I am bar

Comment: The real answer right here.

Answer (score 9):

```
/**
 * @property {String} mode mode of display
 * <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;`video` - display video, or
 * <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;`audio` - plays only the audio
 * @property...
 */
```

Actual output:

[image]